# Restrict vba Find and Replace to the active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, find-replace

I have a workbook consisting of several protected sheets.  I want to use the Excel Find & Replace dialog box but need to unprotect my sheet prior to opening it and reprotect upon closing it.  I am attempting to do this using a command button in which to open the Find & Replace dialog box. I originally attempted to code the command button as follows:

```
Private Sub cbFindReplace_Click()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="*password*"

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaReplace).Show

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="*password*", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _ 
                    Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

The problem is that this opens up the dialog box with out the Options button and thus the ability to restrict the find & replace to the active sheet.  So I replaced the above Show command with the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Find what:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl( _
  ID:=1849, recursive:=True).Execute
```

The Find & Replace dialog box opened contains the Options button and the ability to restrict to active sheet but it is not modal and thus the protect sheet command is executed directly after opening the dialog box and prevents the replace from being done.  Does anyone have a solution that allows the use of the existing Excel Find & Replace dialog box and NOT creating a userform to duplicate that logic.

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error I've got the following code working as you desire.

Please note there are most likely better ways to handle the code whilst waiting for the `find and replace` dialog to close - I didn't have an exact solution to begin with but thought this might work - and it did.

Per [Detecting an Open Dialog Box](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T012356_Detecting_an_Open_Dialog_Box.html) from [wordribbon.tips.net](https://wordribbon.tips.net) I borrowed the code to find the open window for the `Find and replace` dialog. Per the article;

> A dialog box is nothing but an open window, and each dialog box has a name.

Having confirmed this works as I expected, I made a few modifications which I'll explain below the code.

---

### Create a new module in the VBE (or add the following to an existing module)

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal wClassName As Any, ByVal wWindowName As String) As Long
```

*Please note this will not work in a `Sheet` or the `Workbook` module, you will need to add it to one you have created -* **Insert > Module**

---

### Create a function returning a Boolean which determines if your dialog is open or not.

```
Function testDialogOpen() As Boolean
    Dim wHandle As Long
    Dim wName As String

    wName = "Find and Replace"
    wHandle = FindWindow(0&, wName)
    If wHandle = 0 Then
        testDialogOpen = False
    Else
        testDialogOpen = True
    End If
End Function
```

---

### Slight modification to your code to check if the dialog is open or not before protecting the sheet.

```
Sub unprotect_findandreplace_protect()

    Sheet1.Unprotect "abc123"

    Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Find...").Execute

    While testDialogOpen()
    DoEvents
    Wend

    Sheet1.Protect "abc123"

End Sub
```

The `While...Wend` loop evaluates if the `Find and Replace` window is open or not on each iteration. It does so by calling the `testDialogOpen()` Function which returns the `True` or `False` result. The loop will continue to run until the `Find and Replace` dialog is closed, when it will exit the loop and go to the next line, re-protecting the sheet.

---

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.
Unfortunately Samuel's solution didn't works on my computer :/
(Excel show my replace dialog box but I couldn't  use replace function -Excel show error)

This works for me:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
#End If

Sub DialogOpen()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ReplaceDialog")
    DoEvents

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "OnTime"
End Sub


Sub OnTime()
    Dim wHandle As Long
    Dim wName As String

    wName = "Find and Replace"
    wHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, wName)
    DoEvents
    If wHandle = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    Else
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "OnTime"
    End If

End Sub
```